# Is it possible to escape a single quote to inject javascript in html element?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

Comparing 2 html elements

```
const htmlElement = `<p myAttr=${attackerValue}>Appended element!</p>`;
```

It is easy to inject javascript here, I can use an `attackerValue` of `</p><script>alert("injected JS") </script>`

However, if the there are single quotes wrapping `attackerValue` in the htmlElement, is it still possible to inject javascript?

```
const htmlElement = `<p myAttr='${attackerValue}'>Appended element!</p>`;
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/young-hill-4nww5k?file=/src/index.js

Edit: Found my answer, I can simply escape the string single quote by using an input such as `'</p><script>alert("injected JS") </script>`

Comment: Is this question about frontend code in the browser or backend code generating HTML?

Comment: Front end code in the browser. `attackerValue` comes from an input box in the front end. Hopefully my codesandbox demonstrates it better.

Answer (score 2):

For front-end code it does not matter if it is possible. `<script/>` tags inserted via `innerHTML` are not executed:

```
<html>
    Example:
    <script>
        const injection = '<script>alert("hello")<\/script>';
        document.body.innerHTML += ` this is a test ${injection}`;

        // You will never see the "hello" alert because
        // browser ignores your script tag.
    </script>
</html>
```

The browser ignores all script tags inserted into the DOM for exactly this reason - to prevent an injection attack.

It is possible to inject scripts via `document.write()`:

```
<html>
    Example: 
    <script>
        const injection = '<script>alert("hello")<\/script>';
        document.write(` this is a test ${injection}`);

        // You will see the "hello" alert!
    </script>
</html>
```

The solution to that is simple: don't use `document.write()`.